# Finding duplicates in a column, setting conditions, summing values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file and I'm currently using pandas module. Have not found the solution for my problem. Here is the sample, problem, and desired output csv.

Sample csv:

```
project, id, sec, code

1, 25, 50, 01

1, 25, 50, 12

1, 25, 45, 07

1, 5, 25, 03

1, 25, 20, 06
```

Problem:

I do not want to get rid of duplicated (id) but sum the values of (sec) to (code) 01 if duplicates are found given other codes such as 12, 7, and 6. I need to know how to set conditions as well. If code 7 is less than 60 do not sum. I have used the following code to sort by columns. the .isin however gets rid of "id" 5. In a larger file there will be other duplicate "id"s with similar codes.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['id'], ascending=[True])
df2 = df.copy()
sort1 = df2[df2['code'].isin(['01', '07', '06', '12'])]
```

Desired Output:

```
project, id, sec, code

1, 5, 25, 03

1, 25, 120, 01

1, 25, 50, 12

1, 25, 45, 07

1, 25, 20, 06
```

I have thought of parsing through the file but I'm stuck on the logic.

```
def edit_data(df):
sum = 0
with open(df) as file:
    next(file)

    for line in file:
        parts = line.split(',')
        code = float(parts[3])
        id = float(parts[1])
        sec = float(parts[2])

return  ?
```

Appreciate any help as I'm new in Python equivalent to 3 months experience. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
df = df.sort_values('id')

#Use boolean indexing to eliminate unwanted records, then groupby and sum, convert the results to dataframe with indexes of groups.
sumdf = df[~((df.code == 7) & (df.sec < 60))].groupby(['project','id'])['sec'].sum().to_frame()

#Find first record of the group using duplicated and again with boolean indexing set the sec column for those records to NaN.
df.loc[~df.duplicated(subset=['project','id']),'sec'] = np.nan

#Set the index of the original dataframe and use combined_first to replace those NaN with values from the summed, grouped dataframe.
df_out = df.set_index(['project','id']).combine_first(sumdf).reset_index().astype(int)

df_out
```

Output:

```
   project  id  code  sec
0        1   5     3   25
1        1  25     1  120
2        1  25    12   50
3        1  25     7   45
4        1  25     6   20
```

Comment: Wow @Scott Boston this worked great!! Do you mind me asking how you came up with this just so I understand how it works together as a whole?

Comment: First, find group sums without records due to restriction of code == 7 and sec < 60.  Next convert that series to a dataframe.  Now, identity the first record of each group using duplicated and set the sec value to null so we can use combine_first to replace that value after setting the index.

Comment: @Benji Added some comments to the answer, if this helped you would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: In my dataset I just ran into a instance where say "id" 25 had a "code" 3 and the "sec" was summed to "code" 1. So sec for id 25 code 1 ended up being higher then it should have been. How would I add the code to set a restriction to say code != 3

Comment: Replace `df.cold == 7` with `df.code != 3`  You want to sum all codes if greater than 60 however, if less than 60 ignore all codes other than 3?

Comment: Code 7 for sure has to be less then 60. However according to what I'm trying to accomplish some codes should not be summed as it would alternate the meaning. for the example input if there was a row with 1,   25,   25, 3. based on the grouping of the id 25 then the sum would be 145 instead of 120.